# Query mongodb using PHP curl

Tags: php, mongodb, curl, payload

I'm trying to make a query using php through a database in mongo db. But the query is not working correctly. The result is always the same.
I need to view all the sales stored in the database. Can someone help me?

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://namesite.com/teste');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The query should return me a total of 700 sales. But it is returning me the total of data stored in the database and it is not bringing the filter.
I'm waiting. Thank you

Comment: The issue isn't your curl, it's the script on the server. Your code will just show the output of that script. Access it in your browser and see what it displays.

Comment: @David There api was only made to return the numbers of the query. I will not be able to reproduce a specific error. But I managed to make it work with javascript but with php not yet.

Comment: Are you sure you want to send the data encoded with json_encode? If $data is already an array you can just use it like that, unless the server actually expects a json object.

Comment: if you remove the json_encode a following error message appears:
`Bad Request - The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.` @David

Comment: How was it done in javascript?
`query_won = {"stages.won":{"$exists": true}}
var data_leads = {"query":query_won}
var options_leads = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload":JSON.stringify(data_leads)
  };
var response_leads = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlrequest,options_leads);
That way it works. But I needed it to be in php
`

Comment: Is that the contents of ```$data_string```?

Comment: No, this is an example of how it is done with javascript. No examples are working properly. In PHP it does not